# Weird error after \showthe

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

I'm trying to understand the meaning of `\p@` from plain.tex:

```
\newdimen\p@ \p@=1pt % this saves macro space and time
```

While trying to figure it out, I stumbled upon strange behavior.

Consider this:

```
\newdimen\mydimen
\catcode`@=11
\mydimen=10\p@
\showthe\mydimen
```

The result is `10.0pt`

Now add `\nonstopmode` and `\showthe\nointerlineskip` at the beginning, so that it becomes:

```
\nonstopmode
\showthe\nointerlineskip
\newdimen\mydimen
\catcode`@=11
\mydimen=10\p@
\showthe\mydimen
```

The result is `0.0pt`

Following is the log of the second example with `\tracingcommands=1` appended.

```
{vertical mode: \nonstopmode}

{\showthe}
> -1000.0pt.
\nointerlineskip ->\prevdepth 
                              -1000\p@ 
l.4     \showthe\nointerlineskip


{the character -}
{horizontal mode: the character -}
{\dimen11}
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \global 
\alloc@ #1#2#3#4#5->\global 
                            \advance \count 1#1by\@ne \ch@ck #1#4#2\allocati...
l.5     \newdimen\mydimen

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \global 
\alloc@ #1#2#3#4#5->\global 
                            \advance \count 1#1by\@ne \ch@ck #1#4#2\allocati...
l.5     \newdimen\mydimen

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

{\global}
{\count21}
{\global}
{\immediate}
\mydimen=\dimen16
{\catcode}
{\dimen16}
{\showthe}
> 0.0pt.
l.8     \showthe\mydimen


{\par}
{vertical mode: \par}
)
! Emergency stop.
```

The questions are: 1) how `\p@` works; 2) why the value of \mydimen is `0.0pt` in the second case; 3) how to interpret the log.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No weird error, actually. The primitive `\showthe` expands tokens in order to find something good for being shown, the rules are the same as for `\the`.

Since `\nointerlineskip` expands to `\prevdepth -1000\p@` and `\prevdepth` is legal after `\the` when TeX is in vertical mode, the current value of `\prevdepth` is shown, which is `-1000pt`, because TeX is at the start of a vertical list.

Then `-1000` is printed and `\p@` expects a dimension, because it's a dimension register. So the next token is expanded, which is `\newdimen` and no length is found. Error: `Missing number, treated as zero`. TeX tries to recover by inserting `0`, then a unit is missing and TeX adds `pt`, again for error recovering. Then `\newdimen` is performed. Now `\p@` holds the value `0pt`, so `\mydimen=1000\p@` results in setting `\mydimen` to zero.

Plain TeX has

```
\newdimen\p@ \p@=1pt % this saves macro space and time
```

and it turns out that `\p@` is `\dimen11` (but it's irrelevant). When a register appears in the “right-hand side” of an assignment (such as `\dimen0=\p@`, but the `=` is optional), the register's value is used for the assignment; when it appears “alone”, TeX assumes it has to perform an assignment to it and this is the case. You'd get exactly the same error if you typed `the value of \dimen0\ is` in the hope of printing the current value of `\dimen0`. So, while `\dimen0=10\p@` is a correct assignment, `-1000\p@\newdimen` leads to an error.

Since `\p@` is a dimension register, when it appears in the “right-hand side” of an assignment it accepts a factor in front of it, which means multiplication. The default value of `\p@` is 1pt (as shown above), so `\dimen0=3.4\p@` is the same as `\dimen0=3.4pt`; it just requires less tokens and might be abused by changing the value of `\p@` (say `\p@=1bp`, for instance).

If you want to show a macro like `\nointerlineskip`, you need `\show`, not `\showthe`.

*Caveat*: whilst `\showthe` expands the next token until finding an unexpandable one, `\show` *never* expands and displays the meaning of the next token.

Comment: What does it mean, "`\p@` expects a dimension"? Add some examples to the answer please.

Comment: The MWE to reproduce the error is this: `\newdimen\x\x\newdimen\y\showthe\x`. So, for what purpose the next token after second `\x` is expanded? If we put a number there (for length), it changes nothing, i.e., `\newdimen\x\x4\newdimen\y\showthe\x`. What does TeX need to find in the next token, so that no error will be printed?

Comment: As far as I understood, these rules hold: `\p@ = 1pt` and `R\p@ = Rpt`. Are there any other rules, and what `R\p@` means? Multiplication, or some TeX trick?

Comment: @Igor Liferenko: `4` is not a valid dimen because it is missing the unit. Also, you seem to be unaware that the equals sign is optional when setting a register; `\p@4cm` is the same as `\p@=4cm`, and will change the register to contain the value 4 cm.

Comment: @chirlu Right. Everything is clear now.